# Centos 6.5 upgrade Bind from 9.8 to 9.10

Tags: centos, bind

I have centos 6.5 running bind 9.8

```
named -v
BIND 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.37.rc1.el6_7.7
```

I searched around dint find anything relating to bind upgrade.

This is what I am planning:

```
Take snapshot
yum clean all
yum update bind
```

I want to check on:

1. How people have done bind upgrades, should I do slave servers first.
2. What are the things to take care of.
3. Does centos 6.5 support bind 9.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `yum list updates` and look at what versions it would install if you did a `yum update bind` - bind 9.10 is not there.

> Please keep in mind that 6.0, 6.1, 6.2, 6.3, 6.4 and 6.5 no longer gets any updates, nor any security fix's.

- from http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.5/readme

So it's not supported on CentOS 6.5, and never will be. Why? See:

> Because there is a good chance that BIND 9.10 has introduced changes that are not backwards compatible with the prior version. You won't believe how many CentOS BIND installations are out there. Quite a lot of them may have automatic nightly "yum update"s enabled. This is easy to accomplish with yum-cron, btw.
>
> The goal of enterprise operating systems is that doing regular operating system updates should not break anything. The goals are different in other Linux distributions, such as Fedora. Now, if "yum update" updated someone's BIND to 9.10 and it ended up breaking something critical (perhaps even some third party application), the admins taking care of those servers would not be particularly happy. That is why RHEL, and by extension, CentOS, stick with the true and tested versions and backport any security fixes.

- from ["Why CentOS is not using Bind 9.10"](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=46151) dated 2014.

Note that:

> The version that Redhat supplies and CentOS repackages is not the same 9.8.2 that you can get from upstream, it has extra patches and is maintained by Redhat engineers who backport fixes to it. It's not irresponsible, it's secure and tested and stable.

(Although that doesn't apply to CentOS 6.5, because it no longer gets security updates or fixes).

CentOS 7 doesn't use Bind 9.10 either: http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/

Answer (score 1):

In the off-chance that this is still needed, there is now a rpm option on CentOS 6 for BIND 9.11:

https://www.isc.org/blogs/bind-9-packages/